# Open Folder within ClearCase Remote Client using Windows Explorer

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

Is there a way to open the folder location of a file from within CCRC? While I know I can open/copy from directly within CCRC, it is often useful to work directly with the file from within Windows Explorer.

I am looking for something like "open file location" or "open in windows explorer". The folder within CCRC does not appear to allow opening it directly as the double-mouse-click action just expands the tree listing. The path is listed/copyable within the "ClearCase Details" tab, but I am trying to take my laziness to a whole new level by being able to open the folder with a single click.

Any ideas if this is a feature available and where I can find it? Thanks.

Info:
 Rational ClearCase Remote Client 7.1.1
 Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You can try a drag an drop from the CCRC to a windows explorer, but this might not work.
([The reverse works, from CCRC 7.0.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21245031))

If it doesn't work, then this feature isn't available in CCRC 7.x, and should be tested in a CCRC 8.x, where the integration with the OS explorer is tighter (I don't have a CCRC 8.x right now to test it out).